# Best Practice - Access to MVC Model and Document Properties from .js Files

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Given that its best to separate Javascript from HTML View files, what is the best practice for accessing:

- properties of the View Model and
- properties of the document including
  things like 'this' where I need to know information about the calling object

For the former, I have seen [Scott Gu's ToJSON extension method](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/tip-trick-building-a-tojson-extension-method-using-net-3-5), but wanted to know whether this is the best approach.

I've hunted around and not found much other than the above. Is there a good, trustworthy resource?

Thanks,

Chris.

Comment: Are you using some sort of framework like entity to auto-populate view models on your forms, or are you generally asking  how to structure your js to interact with your forms in an MVC style fashion?

Comment: This is either __too broad__, __primarily opinion-based__, or a __request for offsite resource__, any of which is a reason to close. Perhaps you can make it clearer exactly what you're trying to do?

Comment: @FlavorScape The latter.